# UIButton not touchable - customizing from iPhone 4 to iPhone 5

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton, iphone-5

I am working on my app to make compatible to iphone 5. In the following code, donebutton works for iphone 4, but when it comes to iphone5 it is not touchable! I dont know why?

```
 float screenSizeHeight=[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;


if(screenSizeHeight==568)
{
    UIImageView *my_image_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plain_Background2.png"]];
    [my_image_view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,320,568)];
    [self.view addSubview:my_image_view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:my_image_view];

    imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)];
    [doneButtonOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake(124,470,72,28)];
}
if(screenSizeHeight==480)
{
    UIImageView *my_image_view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Plain_Background.png"]];
    [my_image_view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,20,320,480)];
    [self.view addSubview:my_image_view];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:my_image_view];
    imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 400)];
    [doneButtonOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake(124,432,72,28)];
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because in iPhone 5 scrollView height is more and it is above your button.

So change origin y of UIButton.

```
    imageScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460)]; 
// Here imageScrollView bottom is at 480 pixel and doneButtonOutlet origin is at 470 so either small height of scrollview or change button origin y.. 
        [doneButtonOutlet setFrame:CGRectMake(124,470,72,28)];
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: superr, thanks a lot. working during the night drives me crazy! :-) i am going to accept the answer. But I have to wait 5 min .